# Reset Conditional Drop-Down Lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, dropdownlist

I hope you can guide me in a query.

I am performing a search for several items in the worksheet Dashboard, with information that is recorded in Table1 located in the worksheet "Original data". I require that when a new search is performed by selecting another available category in cell C2, in the range of cells (C3:C5) the option --Choose description--, --Choose brand-- and --Choose size/model--, respectively, appears.

In addition, in the range of cells (C7:C10) the option --Reselect criteria-- appears. I have already achieved this with the help of the following macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    Range("C3") = "--Choose Description--"
    Range("C4") = "--Choose Brand--"
    Range("C5") = "--Choose Size/Model--"
End If
If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
    Range("C7") = "<Reselect criteria>"
    Range("C8") = "<Reselect criteria>"
    Range("C9") = "<Reselect criteria>"
    Range("C10") = "<Reselect criteria>"
End If
End Sub
```

Once the value is set in cell C2, the values in cells C3:C5 will appear in their order, corresponding to the search criteria selected in cell C2.

However, I have not been able to get the values corresponding to the search criteria entered in cells C2:C5 to be recorded in cells C7:C10, on the contrary, I keep getting the values "--Reselect criteria--", without being able to modify them.

I need to modify the code to allow me to record the data corresponding to the search criteria selected in cells C2:C5 in cells C7:C10, and thus return the search values as recorded in cells D7:D10.

The formulas that I have entered in the worksheet Dashboard work fine, however the problem is registered in the VBE code, since it only allows me to obtain the result for cells C3:C5, while for cells C7:C10 it does not allow me to perform any calculation, once I have entered the values in cells C3:C5.

I hope I know how to transmit the message of what I require in my search, thank you very much for your valuable attention.

pdt: in link attached file where you can find the workbook with the data shown in the images.

[Workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1alnhU4AVTqI80cPwbDI0iBe4sMKq8IqZ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101869202251884156480&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[image: Dashboard]

[image: Original data]

Comment: I don't understand what you want in C7:C10. Can you explain better? What should (or should not) be in those cells?

Comment: @Camila Sanchez ,,, better U create Dynamic Drop Down/Dependent Drop Down list !!

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio apologies, I didn't know how to explain myself well. Let's go by parts. i. When I modify the search value in cell C2 by an item from those available in the drop-down list, the values in cells C3, C4, C5 and C7:C10 are modified by the default values. "--Choose Descr--","--Choose Brand--",... "<Reselect cri>"
This I have already accomplished with the help of a macro 
If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    Range("C3") = "--Choose Description--"
    Range("C4") = "--Choose Brand--"
    Range("C5") = "--Choose Size/Model--"
    Range("C7:C10") = "<Reselect criteria>"
End If

Comment: ii. Subsequently, as I add values in cell C3, values appear in cells C4 and C5 that correspond to the search criteria in cells C2 and C3.

Comment: iii. Once I have entered the values of cells C2, C3, C4 and C5, in cells C7:C10, the values that appear in cells D7:D10 should be displayed, however, I have not been able to achieve this, since the code does not allow me to register these values.

Comment: I don't know where the error may be registered, or what additional part of the code I should add to make it work correctly. The formulas in the book work quite well, the only thing I have not been able to do is to make the VBE code work well for what I need. I hope to get the message across in the right way, thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Rajesh Sinha thanks for your suggestion, yes it seems to work better that way, the problem is that I need a VBE code that performs the activity in the same way a list would do it. Dynamic Drop Down/Dependent Drop Down list.

Comment: " Once I have entered the values of cells C2, C3, C4 and C5, in cells C7:C10, the values that appear in cells D7:D10 should be displayed", When are you entering those values in C7:C10? On the file, there are no values/no list for C7:C10.

Comment: Exactly, there is no drop-down list for those cells (C7:C10), only the search values corresponding to the selected criteria in cells C2:C5. The formulas I have in cells D7:D10 work perfectly, however, I cannot make them appear once I perform a new search by modifying cell C2. The problem, I think, is in the code that I have, I must enter some modification, but I do not know where the error is. Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few quick changes to your code and formulae.
For the formulae found on your workbook, as D7:D10 are showing `#NA`, their formulae now include `IFERROR` function. For example, D7's formula is now:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Tabla1[Cost per hr ($)],MATCH($C$2&$C$3&$C$4&$C$5,Tabla1[Category]&Tabla1[Description]&Tabla1[Brand]&Tabla1[Size/Model],0)),"")
```

These changes allow to test whether D7:D7 are text or not in the code. If they are text, show the message `<Reselect criteria>`. If they are not, show the cost values. Your code will look like the below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        Range("C3") = "--Choose Description--"
        Range("C4") = "--Choose Brand--"
        Range("C5") = "--Choose Size/Model--"
        Range("C7:C10") = "<Reselect criteria>"
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("d7")) Then  'Check if D7 is text 
        Range("C7:C10") = "<Reselect criteria>"
    Else 'If D7 is not text
        If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
            Range("C7:C10").Value = Range("d7:d10").Value
        End If

    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Notice that I have disabled `Application.EnableEvents` before testing D7, then re-enabled it when done. This is a shortcut I use to avoid error messages. You can remove them and add better error handling.

You have to adapt the code and improve on it for your real data.

Comment: Dear @Reddy Lutonadio, thank you very much for your valuable help, it was very useful, taking into account your explanation I could find a way to adapt the code for what I require, finally I left it as follows:
If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
    Range("C7").Value = Range("I3").Value
    Range("C8").Value = Range("J3").Value
    Range("C9").Value = Range("K3").Value
    Range("C10").Value = Range("L3").Value
End If

Comment: Thanks to your guidance it was possible to find this solution. Again thank you very much, in the next occasions I will transmit my doubts in a simpler way and I will try to explain myself in a less difficult way, a big hug.